# Can there be a way to centrally access wordpress for common developement?

Tags: wordpress

I'm pretty naive to Wordpress.
We are planning to create few websites in Wordpress with a team of 3/4 people. Each of us have installed WAMP/XAMPP on our local machine to use wordpress. But I want to ask whether there is any way to create a central repository and create various websites using this centrally installed wordpress along with a differentiation of individual work?

Answer (score 0):

No. It's not possible to create a central WordPress installation with individual working separately.

Multiple people can still work on a single site as far as both of them are working on different pages.